# How to use Spliterator.trySplit to do parallel computation on N cores?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, spliterator

Let's say I have a list of 10000 elements and want to process them on 6 cores. I don't want to use the existing Stream API and want to do it by myself from scratch (for the learning sake). The Spliterator interface seem to fit well for that purpose. However, it divides the collection in half whenever called. I can get 5000-5000 split, and then do one more split to get 2500-2500-2500-2500, and then 2500-2500-2500-1250-1250 to cut my initial collection into 6 parts. It seems unbalanced and no way to balance it over 6 cores.

From the Java.Doc

> API Note: An ideal trySplit method efficiently (without traversal)
> divides its elements exactly in half, allowing balanced parallel
> computation.

However, the Stream .parallel() seems to solve this problem somehow. I tried to read the source, but still unable to get the gist of it. Maybe someone can explain the high level approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reimplement the functionality provided by parallel streams, then apart from the dividing the task into subtasks, you need to take care about the execution of these stacks and joining the result of the results.

Under the hood, parallel streams make use of the **Fork/Join framework**.

`Spliterator` is needed only split the data into subtasks. But the order of in which worker threads would be assigned with the task and correctness of merging the intermediate result is implemented through Fork/Join.

If you want to do it yourself, you can extend abstract class [`RecursiveTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) and override its method `compute()`. That would be a "container" for your tasks (*there's also* `RecursiveAction` *class which is meant to perform an action and doesn't produce a value, but the question is about computations, and we need and to obtain a result* `RecursiveTask` *is more suitable for this purpose*).

To make it more flexible, you can add a property of type `Function` or `Predicate` which would be provided while instantiating it, but it would be no match for the power and flexibility of parallel streams.

While implementing `compute()` you need to provide the logic for splitting the task. You can use `Spliterator` for that and if source allow accessing random elements (like list or array) it can be done manually.

If you choose to utilize `Spliterator` for dividing the dataset, you can use method `trySplit()`, which returns `Spliterator` which would be `null` data can't be split further. Hence, if `trySplit()` yields `null` you need to process remaining elements of the *current spliterator*. Otherwise, you need to create a *new task* based on the *new spliterator* returned by `trySplit()` and apply `fork()` on it, and then merge the result produced by processing the remaining elements in the *current spliterator* with the value returned the by `join()` method applied on the *new task*.

But **note** with `Spliterator` that you'll face an issue while it comes to processing the data. Contrary to `Iterator` this interface **doesn't** declare methods that allow to access elements directly, it's not what it's meant for.

`Spliterator` offers only a couple of methods which allow to dial with its elements: [`forEachRemaining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html#forEachRemaining(java.util.function.Consumer)) and [`tryAdvance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance(java.util.function.Consumer)). The first one is `void`, the second returns `boolean` value, both expect a `Consumer` as an argument. That means that you'll be forced to use stateful functions (which is **not** a good practice) in order to return a value from the `compute()`.

> want to process them on `6` cores

We can specify the required level of *parallelism* (maximum number of threads that would be occupied simultaneously) by using one of the parameterized constructrs of [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)). Or alternatively, we can make use of the Java 8 factory method [`newWorkStealingPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool(int)) from the `Executors` class.

## Parallel processing using Spliterator

`RecursiveTask` implementation:

```
public static class Task<T> extends RecursiveTask<T> {
    
    private Spliterator<T> spliterator;
    private BinaryOperator<T> accumulator;
    private Predicate<T> predicate = t -> true;
    private T identity;
    
    public Task(Spliterator<T> spliterator, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator, T identity) {
        this.spliterator = spliterator;
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
        this.identity = identity;
    }
    
    public Task(Spliterator<T> spliterator, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator, T identity, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.spliterator = spliterator;
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
        this.identity = identity;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected T compute() {
        Spliterator<T> newSpliterator = spliterator.trySplit();            
        AtomicReference<T> result = new AtomicReference<>(identity);
        
        if (newSpliterator != null) {
            Task<T> newTask = new Task<>(newSpliterator, accumulator, identity, predicate);
            newTask.fork();
            forEachRemaining(spliterator, result);
            return accumulator.apply(result.get(), newTask.join());
        }
        forEachRemaining(spliterator, result);
        return result.get();
    }
    
    private void forEachRemaining(Spliterator<T> spliterator, AtomicReference<T> result) {
        spliterator.forEachRemaining(t -> {
            if (predicate.test(t)) {
                result.set(accumulator.apply(result.get(), t));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`main()` - Let's generate a total of all numbers in the Given Collection, and add up separately all odd and all even elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(6); // required parallelism 6
    
    Set<Integer> test = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(new Task<>(test.spliterator(), Integer::sum, 0)));
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(new Task<>(test.spliterator(), Integer::sum, 0, t -> t % 2 == 0)));
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(new Task<>(test.spliterator(), Integer::sum, 0, t -> t % 2 != 0)));
}
```

*Output:*

```
45   // total of: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
20   // total of: 2, 4, 6, 8
25   // total of: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

## Spliterator + Iterator

We can improve the approach shown above by introducing `Iterator` as an additional property.

That would allow making `Spliterator` to be responsible only for splitting the tasks, meanwhile `Iterator` would be used for processing the data. And it would allow to avoid using stateful functions like in the previous example.

`RecursiveTask` implementation:

```
public static class Task<T> extends RecursiveTask<T> {
    
    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    private Spliterator<T> spliterator;
    private BinaryOperator<T> accumulator;
    private Predicate<T> predicate = t -> true;
    private T identity;
    
    public Task(Iterator<T> iterator, Spliterator<T> spliterator, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator, T identity) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.spliterator = spliterator;
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
        this.identity = identity;
    }
    
    public Task(Iterator<T> iterator, Spliterator<T> spliterator,
                BinaryOperator<T> accumulator, T identity, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.spliterator = spliterator;
        this.accumulator = accumulator;
        this.identity = identity;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected T compute() {
        Spliterator<T> newSpliterator = spliterator.trySplit();
        
        if (newSpliterator != null) {
            Task<T> newTask = new Task<>(iterator, newSpliterator, accumulator, identity, predicate);
            newTask.fork();
            T result = forEachRemaining(iterator);
            return accumulator.apply(result, newTask.join());
        }
        return forEachRemaining(iterator);
    }
    
    private T forEachRemaining(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        T result = identity;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T next = iterator.next();
            if (predicate.test(next)) {
                result = accumulator.apply(result, next);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

`main()` - the same sample data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(6); // required parallelism 6
    
    Set<Integer> test = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(new Task<>(test.iterator(), test.spliterator(), Integer::sum, 0)));
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(new Task<>(test.iterator(), test.spliterator(), Integer::sum, 0, t -> t % 2 == 0)));
    System.out.println(pool.invoke(new Task<>(test.iterator(), test.spliterator(), Integer::sum, 0, t -> t % 2 != 0)));
}
```

*Output:*

```
45   // total of: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
20   // total of: 2, 4, 6, 8
25   // total of: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```